# Reuse Speech Recognition Training Profile on another Computer

Tags: c#, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have developing speech to text conversion application in Android. The basic idea is to record voice in android and send the recorded wav file to a server.

On the server-end i created a C#-Service application that uses the Microsoft Speech Recognition APIs. This service receives the audio wav file from the Android device, converts it to text and sends the recognized text back to the Android device.

This is working fine because many times i have trained the Speech Recognition API.

Now my problem is: Can I use already trained Speech Recognition Profile on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to move your training data, but I have some suggestions for you to consider.

Google provides speech recognition for Android, see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html

If you use the Microsoft Speech Platform instead of the desktop recognizer that comes in Windows 7, you don't need training (you also can't do dictation, but I don't know if you need that). See [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re) for more info.

Comment: Sorry i have not  mentioned on my question i.e I have developing off-line speech to text conversion application in Android. please give me the right direction which APIs is suitable for my application. Initially i am developing for English and Japanese voice to text conversion application.

Comment: If the phone is "off-line" how will it send the recorded voice to your server? Are you saving it and and recognizing it later? If you're phone must have network access, have you tried the google recognizer? For the Microsoft tools, a dictation grammar is only available in the recognizer that ships with the desktop operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the microsoft software available at:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22358

In case you need to do it programmatically, see [Programmatically importing MS Speech API speech profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756695/programmatically-importing-ms-speech-api-speech-profile/34530586#34530586)